# ¿Como integrar font en mi web?

Tags: css, font-faces

Tengo los siguientes `fonts`:

```
Rubik-Bold.ttf
Rubik-MediumItalic.ttf
Rubik-Black.ttf
```

Quiero usar estos `fonts` por ejemplo en cada uno:

```
<p class="bold">Hola</p>
<p class="medium">Hola</p>
<p class="black">Hola</p>
```

Supongo que tendré que hacer en mi `app.css` algo así

```
@font-face { */
  font-family: 'Rubik-Bold.ttf'; 
}
```

y ese fichero `.ttf` tenerlo a la misma altura de mi `app.css`, pero imaginemos que tengo 30 ficheros `.ttf` en una carpeta,

¿Hay alguna forma de importarlos más fácil?

Answer (score 3):

Hola en realidad no si te basas en el ejemplo:

```
<p class="bold">Hola</p>
<p class="medium">Hola</p>
<p class="black">Hola</p>
```

solo podrías definirse la fuente para cada clase y listo:

```
.bold {
  font-family: url('Rubik-Bold.ttf'); 
}
```

Ahora bien si quieres usar `@font-face`, lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera:

```
@font-face { 
    font-family: 'Rubik'; 
    src: url('Rubik-Bold.ttf');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face { 
    font-family: 'Rubik'; 
    src: url('Rubik-Medium.ttf');
    font-weight: 500;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face { 
    font-family: 'Rubik'; 
    src: url('Rubik-Black.ttf');
    font-weight: 300;
    font-style: normal;
}


.bold, .medium, .black {
    font-family: 'Rubik';
}

.bold {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.medium {
    font-weight: 500;
}

.black {
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

Tema de ficheros, puedes tenerlos en rutas relativas y usar path

```
/css
    style.css
/fonts
    /Rubik
        Rubik-Black.ttf
```

Por ejemplo para usar `Rubik-Black.ttf` en `style.css` haría lo siguiente

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Rubik',
    src: url('../fonts/Rubik/Rubik-Black.ttf');
}
```

De todos modos si puedes mejor usa un CDN para almacenar tus archivos estáticos como fuentes.